# Removing Rectangular Border In Polar Plot

Tags: r, plot

I have generated a polar plot in R using ggplot2 and would like to find a way to clear-up the plot in two aspects.  The first is how do I remove the rectangular box around the circular plot that also has the x/y labels and the y tick marks.  The second is how do I remove the extra space in the plot between the last range ring at 15000 and the ring that has the azimuth ticks?  I have placed a self contained example below.  Thank you for any help.

```
# Load needed Libraries ---------------------------------------------------

library(ggplot2)

# Generate Fake Data ------------------------------------------------------

N    = 25
bng  = runif(N, min =  0, max = 360)
rng  = rlnorm(N, meanlog = 9, sdlog = 1)
det  = runif(N, min = 0, max = 1) >= 0.5

det  = factor(det)

data = data.frame(bng, rng, det)

# Generate the Plot -------------------------------------------------------

plot = ggplot(data) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(aes(x = bng, y = rng, color = det), size = 5, alpha = 0.7) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'x', start = 0, direction = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,360), expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(0,360-1, by=45)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15000)) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank()) +
  scale_color_manual(name = '', values = c('red', 'black'), breaks = c(FALSE, TRUE), labels = c('Not Detected', 'Detected'))
plot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theme( panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()) will remove the border, ticks and label

```
  plot = ggplot(data) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(aes(x = bng, y = rng, color = det), size = 5, alpha = 0.7) + 
  theme( panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  coord_polar(theta = 'x', start = 0, direction = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,360), expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(0,360-1, by=45)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15000)) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank()) +
  scale_color_manual(name = '', values = c('red', 'black'), breaks = c(FALSE, TRUE), labels = c('Not Detected', 'Detected'))
 plot
```

Comment: Ok, see that.  However, that still leaves the y-axes tick marks in the upper left corner.  I am guessing that I can explicitly turn off those tick marks along with the labels...  But if I did so, then I am not sure how I would label the radius axes on the polar plot.

It seems as though ggplot2 is not very friendly when it comes to the polar plots...

Comment: theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) removes those

Comment: I see.  That worked well.  Now just need to get that extra space at the edge of the plot figured out.  I am going to go ahead and mark this answer as good though.