# Lines and areas not represented in a radar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the data:

```
structure(list(SAPvsSH = c(-23.8789646372585, NaN, -10.8009305417082, 
-11.8411770633881, -19.000246852629, -14.364572544966, -21.8175372410621, 
-25.4455825234135, -16.3659714913407, -24.2952691912406, -0.794961013892774, 
9.27790872080566, -20.9411764705882, -20.3132576468705, -25.1353910061732, 
-17.0200414318061), Tooth = c("UI1", "LI1", "UI2", "LI2", "UC", 
"LC", "UP3", "LP3", "UP4", "LP4", "UM1", "LM1", "UM2", "LM2", 
"UM3", "LM3")), .Names = c("error", "Tooth"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("UI1", 
"LI1", "UI2", "LI2", "UC", "LC", "UP3", "LP3", "UP4", "LP4", 
"UM1", "LM1", "UM2", "LM2", "UM3", "LM3"))
```

I use `coord_polar()` from `ggplot` to generate a radar chart. This is the code:

```
ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=Tooth, y=error)) + 
  geom_point(size=1.5) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0), lwd=1, lty=2) + 
  geom_area(alpha=0.2, position = position_identity()) +
  coord_polar() + 
  theme_bw()
```

And I get something like this:

[image]

## What do I need?

- **Trace a line that connects all the points** ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50354227/3751263)). The difference with the radar in the link is that here we have only one group and not 3.
- **Color the area defined by the previous line** respect the dashed circle line seen in the previous plot, just in the same way [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356635/3751263). Our reference here is the dashed black line, this is important.
- **Separating the tags from the outer circle**, to avoid tags to be overimposed.
- **Remove the outer square**.

Comment: Could you reformat to have one question per post?

Comment: Remove outer square is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806862/removing-rectangular-border-in-polar-plot